# Ionic Firebase Cloudfunctions Timestamp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

thanks for help. (update the question for clarification)

1.- In ioinic (angular) HTML, I ask for an input: "start".
The html form type is timestamp, so in html I'm able to "graphically" pick a date.

The form is this:

```
<ion-label>Start</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime formControlName="start" type="timestamp" 
    displayFormat="DMMMYYYY" min="2019" max="2070"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

2.- Then I store this in firestore as new Date(value of the input)

```
example--- {start: new Date(start)}
```

Saves in Firestore as timestamp: 15 of july at 01:23:00 utc 5

For the record, if I save just as

```
{start: start}
```

it saves in Firestore as: 2020-07-15T01:23:00-05:00

, but this I'm still unable to display back in html...could the answer be here?

3.- Then, if I get the data and subscribe via html:
Example: (using first shown format)

```
let d of (data| async).....{{d.start.toDate()|date: "dd/MMM/yy"}}
```

shows me date as I want in html...15/jul/2020

4.- If I just pass this same d.start to another function and save to Firestore directly it still saves just as it was saved on the other doc.

5.- the problem is that I pass this data to a callable Cloud Function, as part of data, then, already in the CF function I retrieve:

```
const start = data.start;
```

6.- Here is the problem, no matter how I have tried, it does not get stored to another firebase doc as it was in the other firestore docs.

have tried:

```
const start = new Date(data.start)
const start = new Date(data.start.nanoseconds)
const start = new Date(data.starts seconds)
const start = data.start
const start = data.start.nanoseconds.
etc... many combinations truly, read, searched, googled and can't get it.
```

Sometimes it stores NaN, sometimes just a number of seconds/nanoseconds, sometimes returns 500 invalid date format, sometimes stores as I would wish, but with a 1970's date (this is the closest one)

I'm trying to do the conversion just in the Firestore Cloud Function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Although you need to add some codes since just listing what you have will not let anybody know where your problem could be, but ionic uses ISO time, so when you save data in firebase in the format you want, thus when you refill your data in the form, the dates are set in your format and not in iso format so you need to set the vales in ts file as like declare startDate:Date; and then on data arrive use this.startDate = newDate(here put the value from firebase).toISOString(); and same thing to the end date and thus should work or you could use pipe and map to achieve this.

Comment: Thank U @MostafaHarb, this is useful, I understand the need for code and will try to post asap, still thanks for the idea.

Comment: Thanks @MostafaHarb still haven't solved it

Comment: what still is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was finally solved by using
const start= new Date(data.start.seconds *1000);                                      not sure why when console.log() shows a different format, but when storing it into firestore, it saved it just as I needed, as already stored in other firestore docs via ionic. Thanks for the time and help of those who helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

Ionic uses ISO time, so when you save data in firebase in the format you want, thus when you refill your data in the form, the dates are set in your format and not in iso format so you need to set the vales in ts file as like declare

```
startDate:Date;
```

Then on data arrive use

```
this.startDate = newDate(here put the value from firebase).toISOString();
```

and same thing to the end date and thus should work or you could use pipe and map to achieve this.

**Update Part**

You can save the time normally in iso format in database  yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000z ,so when getting the data from the firebase
As i told you before you fan either use pipe and map to solve it or by this way:

```
const splitedDate = firebaseDate.split('T');
const ymd = splitedDate[0];
// now ymd is yyyy-MM-dd
const time = splitedDate[1].split('.');
// now time is 00:00:00
const customDate = this.formatToDate(ymd.split('-'), time);

formatToDate(dtime, time) {
    const date = new Date(dtime[0], (parseInt(dtime[1]) - 1), dtime[2]); 
    const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' }); 
    return `${dtime[2]} of ${month} at ${time}`;
}
```

Comment: Man, as I understand, right now I'm saving 15 of july at 01:23:00 utc 5, but your suggestion is to save: 2020-07-15T01:23:00-05:00, and I understand this could work, but this brings up a different issue, related to HTML, The way it's stored right now, I use let d of (data| async).....{{d.start.toDate()|date: "dd/MMM/yy"}}
shows me date as I want in html...15/jul/2020, and with the 2020-07-15T01:23:00-05:00 although it could work for the Cloud Function, I cant get there because I get stuck in the display that in HTML, how would that be? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Chucho7 you misunderstood me, the senario is that you save that data in the format you want in fb, by when getting the data back from db, get the value like (new Date(res.date).toISOString()) and thus the date will be changed to picker timezone since timezone don't take value of utc, it take the time in iso format , and thus when re entering the data to db again, you will need to reconvert its value to the format you need in utc. So for faster work, you could do this iso conversion and utc conversion using pipe and map other than setting this conversion for each object using for loop.

Comment: I've come closer, as I would prefer just to do the whole conversion directly in the Cloud Function, by using:                                                                                       
      const start= new Date(data.start.seconds *1000);                                                                what I get is 2020-07-15T01:23:00.000Z , so that is almost right!! I just want to convert that into:   15 of july at 01:23:00 utc 5 when stored in Firestore, do you think that's possible? without messing with the whole ionic setup? thanks!

Comment: @Chucho7 is it always a constant to utc 5? Or it may change to utc 3 or 4 according to user timezone?

Comment: oh, thanks, I'm not concerned about the utc that much, well, maybe out of lack of knowledge, perhaps, or maybe I don't understand the question, sorry, but having it stored in Firestore as Timestamp: 15 of july at 01:23:00 would make thinks so much easier than having it stored as Timestamp: 2020-07-15T01:23:00.000Z

Comment: @Chucho7 you may save it in fire base in iso and i will edit the answer to give you the way how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, @MostafaHarb for your time and interest, it seems like the last solution fixed it for me....using, in the Cloud function const start= new Date(data.start.seconds *1000), that solved, it, thanks for all :)

Comment: @Chucho7 no problem mate and you could use the updated part for future work if needed in you project. Good luck mate <3.